# Set Theory: $ A −B $, $ (A ∪ B)^{c} $, $ (A^{c} ∩ B^{c}) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $X = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11\}$ be the universal set and $ A = \{0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8\}$, and $ B = \{1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11\}$

Find the binary representation of:

a. $ A − B $

b. $ (A ∪ B)^{c} $

c. $ (A^{c} ∩ B^{c}) $

My answers:

a. $ A − B = \{0, 3, 8\} $

Binary Representation: $ (0000, 0011, 1000) $

b. $ (A ∪ B)^{c} = \{2,4,7,9\} $

Binary Representation: $ (0010, 0100, 0111, 1001) $

c. $ (A^{c} ∩ B^{c}) = \{2,4,7,9\} $

Binary Representation: $ (0010, 0100, 0111, 1001) $

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ Should be $$A-B = \{0, 3\}$$
And so the binary representation should be $(0000, 0011).$

But otherwise, everything looks good!

Note that the set in $(2)$ and the set in $(3)$ are equivalent, by [DeMorgan's Rule for sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

That is, for all sets $A, B$, $$(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$$.